# Extend distance for rendering grass and tree objects on terrain

Tags: unity, 3d, terrain-rendering

I am trying to make an adventure game with a big landscape (made the terrain with terrain tools) with 3D models of grass (that I placed using terrain tools) but it only shows the grass/trees that are within a small area. Here is a pic of what I am talking about:

[image: problem]

I would not want to totally remove this because otherwise the framerate will go too low. I just want to make the circle bigger.

thanks (:

Answer (score 0):

Never mind I just couldn't find the tree distance (:
There are so many little things that don't tell you that it even exists or how to find it.

Comment: This answer would be better if it told readers where to find it, so that the next developer to have this problem can learn from your experience.